# How do I export data to Salesforce in android

Tags: android, api, sdk, salesforce, data-export

I would like to export the data(data like email, contact from my api) to salesforce from my own mobile application.

I am using salesforce sdk, currently i can only fetch data from salesforce.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: I followed salesforce developer android page, that narrate fetching data from salesforce only. https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android.